# How do you add onload() for email HTML

Tags: javascript, html, gmail

I am creating an email bot and I want there to be some dynamic data and was wondering if there was `onload()` support in emails like gmail?

`<body onclick="function()">`

Does Gmail support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, no javascript execution is allowed in emails, among many other things.